# proxychains equivalent for windows

Tags: windows-7, proxy

I'm currently using a shadowsocks proxy on linux and doing most of my work through it. When I need to do something I just add `proxychains` before the command to make it use my proxy. I need to run some programs on windows 7 through this same proxy, even after using the "enable system proxy" in shadowsocks, the programs don't use the proxy. Unfortunately proxychains only supports Unix-like OS's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/shunf4/proxychains.exe

---

I wrote proxychains for Windows and Cygwin, which can effectively proxify Win32 and Cygwin apps.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up stumbling on [proxifier](http://proxifier.com/) which worked flawlessly for me

Comment: This is neither free nor open source. Just saying.

Comment: Neither is windows

Comment: @ridderhoff, and? It's not a proxychains alternative then is it? If one, rightly IMHO, presumes the OP was looking at proxychains because it is free. But either way you answer is not invalid or bad, but warrants the explicit note that proxifier costs about $40.

Comment: @BerndWechner It's free if you pirate it.

I made this post in 2018, before the other solution existed. Proxychains-windows was created in 2020 and I accepted it as the correct solution as soon as it was posted. 

I will NOT delete this solution as it is an *alternative to* proxychains even though not *equivalent to* it.

Comment: in my case, chrome just crashed when getting a url